# Calling method from parent of every child in <view> array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is React Native (JSX).

I have parent and child component. Parent component contains array of child components. At certain point I need to pause child components so I need to call a certain method from within each one of them. 
This is how I try to do it:

```
<View style={styles.fruits}>
      {this.state.fruitComponentArray.map((index, value) => (
        <Fruit key={index} style={styles.fruit}
          onStopAnimation={_ => this.deleteElementFromFruitArray(index)}
          onSendCoordinates={(x, y) => this.checkCoordinates2(x, y, value)}
          onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} 
        />
      ))}
    </View>
```

and calling function with button:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={_ => this.child.onPause()}>
```

And then there's is `onPause()` function in child component.

I know that the problem is in ref naming and because I always send one ref it only references the last child component. So instead of pausing all fruits it pauses just the last one, but I don't know how to solve it.

EDIT:

With the help of the programmers below this is what it looks like at the end and it works: 
I have this in constructor

```
this.child = [];
```

This method (new):

```
 callChildrenMethods = () => {
for(var i=0; i<this.state.fruitComponentArray.length; i++){
  this.child[i].onPause();
}
```

}

Array of views:

```
    <View style={styles.fruits}>
      {this.state.fruitComponentArray.map((index, value) => (
        <Fruit key={index} style={{flex:1, position: 'absolute' , height: `${ this.state.heights[index] }%`}}
          onStopAnimation={_ => this.deleteElementFromFruitArray(index)}
          onSendCoordinates={(x, y) => this.checkCoordinates2(x, y, value)}
          onRef={ref => (this.child[index] = ref)}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
```

And finally onClick:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={_ => this.callChildrenMethods()}>
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055464/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-refs/47055553#47055553

Comment: Try creating ref array 
onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)}
instated of this
try this
onRef={ref => (this.child[index] = ref)}
that may to the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating ref array that hold all your refs,
instated of this
onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)}
try this
onRef={ref => (this.child[index] = ref)}
that may to the trick