# Access to a several elements through one ref React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, react-dom

I wanna get access to multiple elements with using `refs` feature. Then after I could iterate through elements of `this.tabs`. Code below doesn't work, how fix it to make work? Solution, which I use now is `document.querySelectorAll('tabs')`, but it doesn't seems right for React.

```js
class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.tabs = React.createRef();
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.tabs);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span class="tab" ref={this.tabs}>One</span>
        <span class="tab" ref={this.tabs}>Two</span>
        <span class="tab" ref={this.tabs}>Three</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Assigning multiple ref instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055464/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-refs/47055553#47055553)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're assigning `refs` incorrect way. Do it in the early beginning of `render()` method:

```
this.tabs = []
```

refs are going to be assigned via

```
<span className="tab" ref={(tab) => { this.tabs.push(tab) }}>One</span>
```

I hope you could call `this.tabs` this case!