# How to Programmatically Assign and Get Refs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if it is possible to programmatically assign and get refs in React. Suppose I wanted to go through a loop creating elements, giving them refs that consist of a name + an index. I know I can assign them like that using strings. However, the only way I know how to access refs consists of using `this.refs.refname` which, as far as I know, precludes me from doing something like `this.refs.{refname + index}`. Is there any way I can do something like this? The source code below should hopefully give you an idea of what I'm asking.

```
render = () => (<div className='row signature-group'>
        <div className='col-md-1 col-xs-2'>
            <b>{this.props.signerDescription}</b>
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-4 col-xs-7'>
            {this.props.signers.map((signer, index) => <div className='text-with-line' key={index} ref={"sig" + index}>{signer}</div>)}
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-2 col-xs-3'>
            {this.props.signers.map((signer, index) => {
                return (index > 0 && this/*.refs.sig+index.value == whateverValue*/) ?
                    (<div className='text-with-line-long-name' key={index}>Date</div>) :
                    (<div className='text-with-line' key={index}>Date</div>);
            })}
        </div>
    </div>)
```

Also, I've heard that using strings to assign refs is considered legacy. Is there any way to programmatically assign refs in a more up-to-date fashion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign refs to multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055464/how-to-assign-refs-to-multiple-components)

Comment: You can use bracket notation like so: `this.refs[refName + index]`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [ref callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to achieve this. The function passed as the `ref` attribute value will be passed the DOM node of the component **once**, after it is rendered:

```
    applyRef = (index, ref) => {
        this[`sig${index}`] = ref;
    };

    render = () => (
        <div className="row signature-group">
            <div className="col-md-1 col-xs-2">
                <b>{this.props.signerDescription}</b>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-7">
                {this.props.signers.map((signer, index) => (
                    <div className="text-with-line" key={index} ref={this.applyRef.bind(this, index)}>
                        {signer}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                {this.props.signers.map((signer, index) => {
                    return index > 0 && this[`sig${index}`].clientHeight > 0 ? (
                        <div className="text-with-line-long-name" key={index}>
                            Date
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="text-with-line" key={index}>
                            Date
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to create a new `property` on your class component (`this`) and then you access it with the same name (this.sig1, this.sig2).

String refs are deprecated and should no longer be used. Your `refs` are now applied directly to the component instance (this).

Comment: I'll mark this as answered once I give it a shot at work tomorrow. This answer deserves an upvote regardless because you made me aware that backquote strings are a thing.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work. I checked the console in my browser's developer mode and it didn't recognize value as a defined property. My guess is that `this[\`sig${index}\`]` isn't an Element. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Makes sense, we are adding the ref to a `div` which doesn't have a value. You can use `innerText` to get the `signer` value. What value are you trying to get from the div?

Comment: I'm trying to get `clientHeight`.

Comment: Then do ```this[`sig${index}`].clientHeight``` to get the height of each div

Comment: Still having problems. Right now the refs are added to divs like this:
`<div className='col-md-4 col-xs-7'>
    {this.props.signers.map((signer, index) => <div className='text-with-line' 
    key={index} ref={this.applyRef.bind(this, index)}>{signer}</div>)}
</div>`

Comment: And using them looks like this:
`<div className='col-md-2 col-xs-3'>
   {this.props.signers.map((signer, index) => {
    const TWO_LINE_NAME_HEIGHT = 50;
    return (index > 0 && this[`sig${index - 1}`].clientHeight >= TWO_LINE_NAME_HEIGHT) ?
     (<div className='text-with-line-long-name' key={index}>Date</div>) :
     (<div className='text-with-line' key={index}>Date</div>);
   })}
  </div>`

Comment: The error in the console reads `cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined`.

Also, I apologize in advance for the way the code came out in the comments. I can't format them nicely.

Comment: Looks like it's because `sig-1` doesn't exist. `this.sig0` is your first ref. So this line: ```this[`sig${index - 1}`]``` is causing it to fail

Comment: That's odd. In the `if` statement I check to make sure that index is greater than 0. The first index is skipped in the loop, so `\`sig${index - 1}\`` should presumably evaluate to `"sig0"` at the lowest. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Can you add `{console.log(this.sig0)}` in your render method return after the `map` and see if it logs out a div? Or add ```console.log(this[`sig${index}])``` to the `applyRef` method? and maybe a `console.log(index); console.log(ref)` in the `applyRef` method to make sure our params are in the right order.