# How can select DOM element, when CSS have an UID with REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I work on a big project and I need to select a DOM element.

Normally I used `refs` element, but I need to make a `querySelectorAll`, except that all element on the DOM look like that : `navwrapper-uDuls5` and It's very difficult for make a `querySelectorAll`

Do you have an approach ?

**EDIT :**

The UID came from Webpack.

```js
const cssLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:6]', // HERE
          minimize: false
        }
      },
      'resolve-url-loader',
      'sass-loader',
      'postcss-loader',
      'font-loader'
    ],
    publicPath: './assets/'
  }),
  exclude: /node_modules/
};
```

Comment: Did you tried something like that: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[class^="navwrapper"]'));`?

Comment: I think I found, I think it's strange : `console.log(document.querySelectorAll(`.${style.subNavWrapper}`));`
What do you think ?

Comment: Probably not if you haven't other ways. But why you can't use `refs`?

Comment: I have a method like `displayMenu` and inside I need to loop on all my `subNavWrapper` and when using `ref` He give me the current ref not all refs :)

Comment: Try to read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055553/6362442).