# onChange callback returns wrong id

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

const handleClick = () => {
  if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.click();
};

return (
    <Container fixed>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          {data &&
            data.map(category => (
    ...
    <Link to={`/products/${category.id}`}>
    ...
<input
  accept="image/*"
  hidden
  type="file"
  ref={inputRef}
  onChange={e => handleChange(e, category.id)}
/>
<IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
  <InsertPhoto />
</IconButton>
```

For some reason, the Link component category.id is 1 but in handle change, I simply console log the id and it returns 10 (the last category.id) how is this possible? the full code can be found here https://pastebin.com/ZiDTkdTU

Comment: Please provide a fiddle link instead of pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is `ref` you're using.

You have several categories (you mentioned 10) in `data` array. But there is only one `inputRef` exists. So when iterating over array you bind this single ref to every input. At the end `inputRef` is bound to last `<input>` element.

Then you click `<IconButton>` to insert photo and this click is transferred to `<input>` element, which opens file selection dialog (as it has `type="file"`). But whatever `<IconButton>` click is always transferred to last `<input>` element as you have single `inputRef`. So `onChange` is also fired for last input always, showing you `id === 10`.

The problem is becomes worse as `<input>` elements are hidden and you don't see what `<input>` element accept file.

The solution is to create array of refs, each for single `<input>`.

Here is [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56828846-7rnm5) to showcase this effect. Whatever 'Select file' button you choose, file will be selected for last `<input>` and console will always log 3.

Here is correct [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56828846corrected-f64gc) which uses ref array.

Comment: Could you show me some example of creating an array of refs? as far as I know this is not possible

Comment: You may look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055464/how-to-assign-refs-to-multiple-components. This describes how to use array of refs